# Center and axis of Quadratic Surface

Tags: algebraic-geometry, quadratics

Given a Quadratic Surface in the form:

$ax^2+by^2+cz^2+2fyz+2gzx+2hxy+2px+2qy+2rz+d=0$

I know how to decide which kind of surface is represented (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/QuadraticSurface.html). How can I find center and axis of this Quadratic Surface?

Comment: There are so many types that "the center" and "the axis" seem to be vague terms until you look at a specific case.

Comment: In other words, I am looking for an affine tranformation plus a translation, which removes all the mixed terms (like $2fyz$) and only leaves the quadratic terms and a scalar, like the equations in the above linked page. The translation would be the (negative) center, The principal axis would be transformed to the standard x, y and z axis.

Comment: Gerhard-- That sounds like it might be possible, maybe first "complete the squares" to get the center, and then do something like is done in 2d to make $xy=1$ into $x^2-y^2=1$ after a rotation... however I don't immediately know the procedure. So just to be clear, for an answer you want the center and possible affine transform algebraically in terms of the original list of 9 or 10 parameters? Might be a mess even if it could be written down simply, but as I say I'm not up on this enough yet.

Comment: coffeemath: right, I think it has to do something with the Eigenvectors of the matrix, when I write the qudratic surface in the form $x^TAx + d = 0$. I am working on it and will post the result, when I find it.

Comment: Gerhard-- Yes I noticed that to do what you want is to diagonalize a 3 by 3 symmetric matrix with real entries. It's known that in this case there are indeed (counting multiplicities) three real eigenvalues. But finding them means solving a general cubic, unless looking at a specific case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the Hessian matrix $H$ of second partials picks out the quadratic form terms. We can name a column vector $p$ and write your polynomial as
$$ \frac{1}{2} x' H x + p' x + d, $$
where $x', p'$ are the transposes of the column vectors $x,p.$

If $H$ is invertible there is a center. Written as a column vector, the gradient of the polynomial is
$$ H x + p.  $$ The center is at $- H^{-1}p.$ Indeed, if we write
$$ x = y - H^{-1} p, $$ your polynomial comes out to
$$  \frac{1}{2} y' H y + \left( d -  \frac{1}{2} p' H^{-1} p \right) $$ 
At this point you still have an eigenvector problem to find an axis.

If $H$ is not invertible various things may happen...

Comment: wouldn't it be $\frac{1}{2} y' H y + \left( d -  \frac{1}{2} p' H^{-1} p \right)$?

Comment: to complete the answer: the eigenvectors of $H$ are the axis. Since $H$ is symmetric, it is numerically easy to compute the eigenvectors (Householder).